# LUA: add values in nested table

Tags: lua, nested

I have a performance issue in my application. I would like to gather some ideas on what I can do to improve it.  The application is very easy: I need to add values inside a nested table to get the total an user wants to pay out of all the pending payments. The user chooses a number of payments and I calculate how much it is they will pay.

This is what I have:

```
jsonstr = "{    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "pending_payments": [
        {
            "month": "january",
            "amount": 50,
        },
        {
            "month": "february",
            "amount": 40,
        },
        {
            "month": "march",
            "amount": 45,
        },
    ]
}"

local lunajson = require 'lunajson'
local t = lunajson.decode(jsonstr)
local limit   -- I get this from the user
local total = 0;

for i=1, limit, 1 do 
    total = total + t.pending_payments[i].amount; 
end;
```

It works. At the end I get what I need.  However, I notice that it takes ages to do the calculation. Each JSON has only twelve pending payments (one per month). It is taking **between two to three seconds to come up with a result!**. I tried in different machines and LUA 5.1, 5.2., 5.3. and the result is the same.

Can anyone please suggest how I can implement this better?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not valid Lua code. Use a long string to define `jsonstr`.

Comment: Hi @lhf. Thanks for the comment. What's in the code is for illustration purposes. In the actual application a JSON object is decoded into a table by lunajson.

Answer (score 1):

For this simple string, try the test code below, which extracts the amounts directly from the string, without a json parser:

```
jsonstr = [[{    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "pending_payments": [
        {
            "month": "january",
            "amount": 50,
        },
        {
            "month": "february",
            "amount": 40,
        },
        {
            "month": "march",
            "amount": 45,
        },
    ]
}]]

for limit=0,4 do
    local total=0
    local n=0
    for a in jsonstr:gmatch('"amount":%s*(%d+),') do
        n=n+1
        if n>limit then break end
        total=total+tonumber(a)
    end
    print(limit,total)
end
```

Comment: Hi @lhf. Thanks for the suggestion. I work with Web Services that provide me with different JSON objects. The one I posted is a short version for illustration purposes. The actual JSON object is actually longer. However, more important I use the information in many differents parts in my code, it would really help me if I can keep using the JSON parser. I was looking into the Pelight library for alternatives and I think there is one but I cannot really understand how to use it (https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.tablex.html#reduce) I am not the most experienced developer.

Comment: @Wilmar, try asking in the Lua mailing list: http://www.lua.org/lua-l.html

Comment: Thank you @lhf. I just did.

Answer (score 1):

I found the delay had nothing to do with the calculation in LUA. It was related with a configurable delay in the retrieval of the *limit* variable.

I have nothing to share here related to the question asked since the problem was actually in an external element.

Thank @lfh for your replies.